# Entity Framawork no valida el modelo a causa de la foreign key con MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework, model-view-controller, modelos

Hola como va? tengo una clase Medico que hacer referencia a otra clase de Especialidades, en la clase Medico tengo el campo EspecialidadFK, para referenciar a la especialidad, mas un public virtual a la propia clase Especialidad, todo funciona bien pero cuando quiero crear un nuevo Medico el if (ModelState.IsValid) devuelve un False, el error que me marca es que no estoy pasando "Especialidad", entiendo que Especialidad en la clase Medico estaría como de adorno, no existe en realidad. Vi varios tutoriales y pareciera que es correcto lo que estoy haciendo las tablas y la FK se crearon correctamente en la base de datos pero no valida el modelo, si saco el if(ModelState.IsValid) el registro se graba correctamente.
Alguien tiene idea como evitar el error de la validación del modelo?

El proyecto es de .net 6 mvc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes convertir la propiedad `Especialidad` en nulleable, esto lo puedes hacer agregando el sufijo `?` al tipo de datos

```
public virtual Especialidad? Especialidad {get; set;}
```

Desde .net 6 se es más riguroso con los tipos de datos que pueden ser nulos, ya que la poca validación de ellos genera bug indeseados. Esto te los está avisando Visual Studio cuando te subraya en verde dicha propiedad.

Puedes deshabilitar esta característica si abres el archivo `.csproj` con un editor de texto y comentas la parte donde dice `Nulleable`

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <!--<Nullable>enable</Nullable>-->
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Esta opción yo no la recomiendo en ningún caso. Al principio es molesto tanto reclamo por objetos que pueden ser nulos, pero realmente evita errores no forzados.

---

Por otro lado te comento que hay ciertas convenciones para nombrar las propiedades. Por ejemplo

```
public class Medico{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int EspecialidadId {get;set;}
}
```

Al usar el nombre `Id` no es necesario usar el atributo `[Key]` arriba de él y `EspecialidadId` se compone de `Nombre_otra_Entidad+Id` ya no es necesario usar  `[ForeignKey].` Puedes leer más [aquí](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions).

Por último veo que usas `virtual`, me da la impresión que no sabes para qué es. Se usa para carga diferida, yo te recomiendo usar preferentemente la "carga diligente", la cual carga las entidades relacionadas solo cuando tú lo explicitas usando `include` (además de quitar la palabra virtual), puedes leer más [aquí](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/querying/related-data?redirectedfrom=MSDN#lazy).

Comment: Si era eso le agregue el ? y ya no me aparece el error de la validación del modelo, estoy arrancando con .net y c#, y no sabia como poder hacer que esa propiedad sea opcional, lo de virtual lo agregue porque vi algunos tutoriales o ejemplo que lo hacían así.